# Guardar plantillas personalizadas o genéricas para las colas de revisión

Tags: característica-nueva, colas-de-revisión

He tenido ya un poco de experiencia en las colas de revisión y desde que ganas el privilegio se observa un patrón constante sobre los problemas por los que reportan las preguntas o respuestas.

Para mí esta tarea es **bastante repetitiva**. Por ejemplo, preguntas de usuarios nuevos que no han leído el recorrido o el artículo sobre cómo preguntar, o las respuestas de personas que hacen preguntas o comentarios en vez de respuestas.

En mi opinión sería una característica bastante atractiva y eficaz que los usuarios pudieran guardar plantillas que hayan realizado sobre cada reporte. Me explico:

**La pregunta está reportada como:**

- Necesita detalles o aclaraciones: Y me aparezca un texto A
- Basada en opiniones: Y me aparezca un texto B
- Muy baja calidad: Y me aparezca un texto C

**La respuesta está reportada como:**

- No es una respuesta: Y me aparezca un texto D
- Contenido no deseado: Y me aparezca un texto E

**Los textos** A, B, C, D, etc. **serían plantillas** de comentarios que:

1. Aparezcan como sugerencia general para todos (Creo que sería la más fácil y viable)
2. Que cada usuario pueda personalizar y guardar su plantilla

Mi idea sería que no apareciera directamente como comentario sino, como un cuadro del que puedas copiar el texto. Algo así:

[image: Propuesta]

Sé que es fácil y bastante utilizado el método de **guardar nosotros mismos** estas plantillas en nuestros dispositivos, sin embargo, creo que sería una gran característica para las colas de revisión. Ayudaría a ahorrar bastante tiempo y evitaría que los usuarios tuvieran que guardar archivos por aparte y tener que buscarlos y abrirlos cada que se deciden a ayudar con las colas de revisión.

Igual podría ser que incluyan un botón o un *dropdown* para ver otras plantillas

Comment: Sobre todo, porque veo que muchos usuarios siempre ponen los mismos comentarios en las publicaciones reportadas. Sin embargo, no sé si sea posible por eso de que es una empresa privada la que mantiene el código

Comment: Por las dudas, ¿conoces: https://github.com/Benjol/SE-AutoReviewComments ?

Comment: Y si queres las plantillas de los mensajes para usar con lo de arriba, esta en mi git....